# Why doesn't Windows 8 allow setting up File History if Windows 7 File Recovery is configured

Tags: windows-8, backup, file-history

Is there any specific reasons why Windows 8 does not allow using *File History* in addition to *Windows 7 File Recovery*? The latter feature is known as *Backup and Restore* in Windows 7.

If I setup File History first, and then Windows 7 File Recovery, both seem to co-exist.

If I setup Windows 7 File Recovery, then I cannot use File History:

> Windows 7 backup is currently configured and must be disabled to configure File History.
>
> [image: Windows 7 backup is currently configured and must be disabled to configure File History.]

What is the downside of using both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I setup File History first, and then Windows 7 File Recovery, both seem to co-exist.

In that case, and based on some research that I did, it seems like you can work around the problem by *temporarily* disabling the backup service:

1. Find *Windows Backup* in the list of services.
2. Stop it if it's running.
3. Disable the service:

   1. Either double-click it or right-click it and then click **Properties**.
   2. Set **Startup type** to **Disabled**

At this point the Windows File History tool in Control Panel should now work properly. After you have File History setup the way you want, re-enable Windows Backup service by changing its startup type to **Manual**. All should be well.

As to the "why" for this, I couldn't begin to guess.